# Set default xdg-open application to terminal program

Tags: arch-linux, terminal, xdg-open

Is it possible to use terminal vim with xdg-open?

I don't have a GUI text editor because I only use vim through the terminal. (I don't care very much for gvim either.) Is it possible to tell xdg-open to open a terminal, then open vim with the selected file?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm posting a partial answer so people can complete them later. I haven't understood which types of files you want to open with vim. I'm assuming text/plain only.

Answer (score 11):

In either your .bashrc or .zshrc, depending whether you use bash or zsh respectively, export these two environment variables:

```
export EDITOR=vim
export VISUAL=vim
```

Adittionally, you might want to associate vim to the mimetype of text files:

```
xdg-mime default vim.desktop text/plain
```

Now you'll have to create a vim.desktop file in `/usr/share/applications`, which should execute the terminal emulator you want, opening vim.

Answer (score 9):

I have to add a new answer, even if my comment only completes the answer by [thiagowfx](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/41858/thiagowfx), because in the comments you cannot indent code.

The content of `vim.desktop` can be something like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Vim Text Editor
Comment=Edit text files
Exec=vim
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Icon=terminal
Categories=Utility;TextEditor;
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/plain;
```

I prefer to put it under `~/.local/share/applications`.

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR

```
$ xdg-mime default vim.desktop <MIMETYPE>
```

Or edit `~/.config/mimeapps.list`. 
MIMETYPE is the output of `$ xdg-mime query filetype <interested-file>`

---

If you are using some Desktop Environment (KDE, GNOME, LXQT, etc), you should refer to your DE's documentation.
But there is the [XDG standard](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/mime-apps-spec-1.0.html) for setting default applications for specific mime-types.
Mime-type is a way to distinguish one type of file from another, see on Wikipedia, or [archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_MIME_Applications#Shared_MIME_database). For example, there is `text/html` mime-type for `*.html` files, and `text/plain` for `*.txt` files. You can determine mime-type with `$xdg-mime query filetype <file_you_interested>`.

Mime-types are used to link applications with files, which these applications should open. 
Open `~/.config/mimeapps.list` wich looks something like this on my machine:

```
[Default Applications]
x-scheme-handler/http=firefox.desktop
...
inode/directory=org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop

[Added Associations]
application/x-shellscript=nvim-qt.desktop;
...
application/pdf=firefox.desktop;
```

Add to `[Default Applications]` section these lines

```
text/plain=vim.desktop
text/markdown=vim.desktop
text/html=vim.desktop
```

(Add another mime-types, if you need them)

`vim.desktop` is the file in `/usr/share/applications` with the following content on my machine:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Vim
TryExec=vim
Exec=vim %F
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Keywords=Text;editor;
Icon=gvim
Categories=Utility;TextEditor;
StartupNotify=false
MimeType=text/english;text/plain;text/x-makefile;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-c++src;text/x-chdr;text/x-csrc;text/x-java;text/x-moc;text/x-pascal;text/x-tcl;text/x-tex;application/x-shellscript;text/x-c;text/x-c++;
```

(Really, there is a lot of translations of names and comments, but they don't matter here)

Look at line `Terminal=true`.

By the rules in XDG Desktop Entry Specification, this line says that launcher should open the terminal emulator, and then in this terminal window should be opened your app (`Exec` line). Fine, yes?

---

However, there is a [five-year-old bug in xdg-open](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xdg/xdg-utils/-/issues/84) and xdg-open ignore `Terminal` key because there is no specification for the default terminal emulator.

( [They tried](https://xdg.freedesktop.narkive.com/bL3IsaJQ/spec-to-define-the-default-terminal#post11), but in 2020 there is no spec yet. )

So if you not using DE, xdg-open doesn't respect Desktop Entry Specification for you.
The person that filled bug had created a patch (which was ignored, sadly), that looks at $TERMINAL variable and open terminal emulator, so you can patch your /usr/bin/xdg-open (or `$ which xdg-open`).

If you don't want to change `xdg-open` script yourself, you can use some workarounds:

1. You can use `gvim.desktop` (if you had `gvim` in your system) or `nvim-qt.desktop` (qt front-end for `neovim`).
2. You can create a file with some name like `my-vim.desktop` with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=MyVim
Exec=<COMMAND TO RUN YOUR TERMINAL> vim %F
Terminal=false
Icon=gvim
Categories=Utility;TextEditor
```

And place it in `~/.local/share/applications`.
Command to run your terminal you can get from the manual page of the prefered terminal (for example, `gnome-terminal -e`). 
More details in Desktop Entry Specifications.

3. You can somehow read the `xdg-open` source code and tweaks your system that `xdg-open` will think you are using DE and call DE-specific tools, but I think it is strange.

---

Useful links:
XDG-mime manual page - https://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-mime 
Arch wiki about XDG mime types - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_MIME_Applications 
Arch wiki about XDG Desktop entry - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries#Application_entry 
xdg-open issue - https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xdg/xdg-utils/-/issues/84