# Arch linux + I3 + URXVT: ROFI opens nano editor in bash instead of URXVT

Tags: arch-linux, mime-types, rxvt, nano, dmenu

The bash script that uses ROFI is:

```
xdg-open "$(locate home | rofi threads 0 -dmenu -i -p "locate:")"
```

This works fine from URXVT (command line), but when I bind this to a key and open ROFI, Every thing works (for example the directory opens in thunar) except when I try to open a text file like .Xdefault

I have already checked my mime settings and it works, because the file opens fine with nano using mimeopen and xdg-open.

Something happens in the background, because  when I exit out of I3, I see the file open in nano along with some gibberish. I can X out of nano to get to the bash prompt.

Normally I don't ask questions, but I am not even sure how to check for a solution. please let me know how this can be fixed.

Edit: 
Just be clear when I open the same text file in I3 using xdg-open it opens it in nano (in the same urxvt terminal).
"xdg-mime query default text/plain"  returns  "nano.desktop"

Comment: ' xdg-mime query default text/plain' returns nano.desktop

Comment: I also have a nano.desktop entry and I updated my mime database with update-mime-database

Comment: is it possible to open a new terminal with xdg-open

Comment: sorry, I had mentioned I could open the file using mimeopen but there is an error "can't exec "x-term": no such file or directory

Comment: Solved: Finally realized that I needed to install xterm. now it opens up nicely in xterm using nano. Not very pretty, but I can fix that.

Comment: Still don't understand why it needs a XTERM when it  should open it in urxvt (btw i replaced xdg-open with mimeopen)

Answer (score 0):

There is no mime-type associated with a command-string, so [`xdg-open`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-open) runs the shell command in the parent terminal (outside **`i3`**) rather than opening a terminal to run the command.

You can work around this limitation by making a ".desktop" file to launch the command as suggested in *[Set default xdg-open application to terminal program](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177976/set-default-xdg-open-application-to-terminal-program)*

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a temp fix by installing xterm and have the text files open in xterm using nano. However I do not understand why it does not use URXVT and nano to do the same thing